# Plot section of a NetCDF and overlay a shape file- R

Tags: r, plot, shapefile, netcdf

I've been plotting a NetCDF file and overlay a shape file. However it's a worlwide image and I only want a section of it i.e. only Mexico.
I used [This tutorial](https://rpubs.com/alobo/vectorplot) to plot everything and works perfect. But in which part should I crop the map.
Here is my code:

```
require(utils)
require(colorRamps)
require(RNetCDF)
require(rasterVis)
require(rgdal)


Datos <- open.nc("./ERAII_viento_2014_300.nc")

u <- var.get.nc(Datos, "u")
v <- var.get.nc(Datos, "v")
lon <- var.get.nc(Datos, "longitude")
lat <-- var.get.nc(Datos, "latitude")

u[u == -32767] <- NA
v[v == -32767] <- NA

u9 <- raster(t(u[ , ,9])[ncol(u):1, ])
v9 <- raster(t(v[ , ,9])[ncol(v):1, ])

y <- brick(u9,v9)
projection(y) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
extent(y) <- c(min(lon), max(lon), min(lat), max(lat))


slope <- sqrt(y[[1]]^2 + y[[2]]^2)
aspect <- atan2(y[[1]], y[[2]])


cntry <- readOGR(dsn="./shape_countries", layer="country")

we <- crop(y, extent(c(0, (180* res(y)[1]), min(lat), max(lat))))
ww <- crop(y, extent(c((180 * res(y)[1]), 360 * res(y)[1], min(lat), max(lat))))
extent(ww) <- c(-180 * res(y)[1], 0, min(lat), max(lat))

#extent(ww) #-180.50:0 y -90:90
#extent(we) #0:180.5 y -90:90
y2 <- merge(ww,we)

slope2 <- sqrt(y2[[1]]^2 + y2[[2]]^2)
vectorplot(y2 * 1.5, isField = "dXY", region = slope2, margin = FALSE, par.settings = rasterTheme(region = matlab.like(n = 10)),narrows = 10000, at = -15:50) + layer(sp.polygons(cntry))
```

I downloaded the wind data from: http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/interim-full-daily/levtype=sfc/ NOTE: I used nco.exe to convert the variables u and v, from "short" to "float".
I don't remember where I got the shapefile but I think it was from ArcGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, that tutorial makes things *much* more complicated than needed. All you need to do is:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)    

u <- brick("./ERAII_viento_2014_300.nc", var="u")
v <- brick("./ERAII_viento_2014_300.nc", var="v")
```

To crop the data to Mexico:

```
mex <- getData('GADM', country='MEX', level=0)
ux <- crop(u, mex)
uv <- crop(v, mex)
```

I do not have your file, but I downloaded one:

```
f <- "_grib2netcdf.nc"
b <- brick(f, var="u10")
```

Note that longitude goes from 0 to 360 (climatologists do that), instead of the standard -180 to 180.

```
extent(b)
#class       : Extent 
#xmin        : -0.375 
#xmax        : 359.625 
#ymin        : -90.375 
#ymax        : 90.375
```

To fix that:

```
bb <- rotate(b)

bb
#class       : RasterBrick 
#dimensions  : 241, 480, 115680, 31  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution  : 0.75, 0.75  (x, y)
#extent      : -179.625, 180.375, -90.375, 90.375  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#data source : in memory
#names       : X2016.01.01, X2016.01.02, X2016.01.03, X2016.01.04, X2016.01.05, X2016.01.06, X2016.01.07, X2016.01.08, X2016.01.09, X2016.01.10, X2016.01.11, X2016.01.12, X2016.01.13, X2016.01.14, X2016.01.15, ... 
#min values  :   -17.75753,   -30.02454,   -27.94626,   -18.51657,   -24.09466,   -22.60716,   -26.89947,   -24.13576,   -19.69050,   -20.82237,   -29.23778,   -20.65125,   -20.09774,   -26.92337,   -27.70344, ... 
#max values  :    21.46595,    22.34927,    25.07379,    24.71817,    20.92774,    21.60935,    24.50690,    23.31480,    24.46388,    25.14835,    26.64731,    21.74223,    20.15436,    29.76378,    27.18361, ... 
#Date/time   : 2016-01-01, 2016-01-31 (min, max)
```

Now you can do:

```
mex <- getData('GADM', country='MEX', level=0)
bbmex <- crop(bb, mex)
```

Comment: Thank you, I do get the shape of Mexico, but when I use "crop" I get this error: Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap.
I read you could use the "extent" function to see if the overlap and they do, or maybe I am doing something wrong.